# Change Conditional statement into a loop

Tags: ruby

The code isn't as clean as I want it to be.

I've been stuck thinking about how I could use a loop instead of a conditional statement. I tried using a `while` loop but to no avail since it didn't make any sense. I'm assuming another `for` loop would be the trick but I've been stuck on this for a few days now.

```rb
x = 0

for question in quiz
    puts(question["question_text"])
    puts(question["choices"])
    puts("")
    puts("What is your answer?")
    answer = Integer(gets())

    if answer == 1 && question == quiz[0]
        puts("You scored correctly!")
        x=x+1
    elsif answer == 2 && question == quiz[1]
        puts("You scored correctly!")
        x=x+1
    elsif answer == 1 && question == quiz[2]
        puts("You scored correctly!")
        x=x+1
    else    
        puts("You scored incorrectly!")
    end
end

puts("You scored " + String(x) + " Out Of " + String(quiz.size))
```

Comment: A [`case`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.4/doc/syntax/control_expressions_rdoc.html#label-case+Expression) expression might fit the bill here.  YMMV.

Comment: would i need to store a `boolean` attached to the `quiz["question"]["choices"]`, to represent if they are `true` or `false`?

Comment: Tip: Consider using `answer = gets.to_i` instead of the irregular `Integer(...)` casting. Also since you don't really care if it's an integer or not, compare to `'1'` instead, like `answer = gets.chomp` to remove newlines.

Comment: Tip: Use `question.each do |quiz|` instead of `for` which isn't really used in Ruby. The `each do` approach gives you access to way more tools, like `each_with_index` and so on.

Comment: Tip: Use string interpolation, like `"You scored #{x} ..."` instead of this highly irregular `String(x)`. I'm not sure where you picked up that habit from, but no Ruby introduction I know of would ever advocate that way. That seems like Python-accented Ruby.

Comment: The real question here is why you can't do `if answer == question['answer']`, or in more Ruby-flavoured terms, `if answer == question[:answer]` using Symbol keys.

Comment: I picked up a book for 5 bucks on epub and I guess I get what I payed for

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to prepare the array of answers upfront and iterate through questions, collecting the number of correct answers.

```
answers = [1, 2, 1]
score =
  quiz.zip(answers).reduce(0) do |score, (question, correct_answer)|
    puts question["question_text"]
    puts question["choices"]
    puts ""
    print "What is your answer? "
    answer = gets.to_i

    if answer == correct_answer
      puts("You scored correctly!")
      score + 1
    else    
      puts("You scored incorrectly!")
      score
    end
  end

puts "Total score: #{score}"
```

The code is untested, but it should work.